# Left and Right Join Giving the same output

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join, right-join

Im trying to do Left and Right join but its not working properly . Lemme show you..

**Student Table**

[image: Student Table]

**Address Table**

[image: Address Table]

**What's i'm doing?**

1. `SELECT * FROM student JOIN address ON student.tid = address.stud_tid`

**Output**:

[image: Simple Join]

2. `SELECT * FROM student LEFT JOIN address ON student.tid = address.stud_tid`

**Output**:

[image: Left Join]

3. `SELECT * FROM student RIGHT JOIN address ON student.tid = address.stud_tid`

**Output**:

[image: Right Join]

May i know why im getting the same out put in every case ?

it should be like rows output like this one

[image: Output Join]

Comment: For every `student.tid` you have a  `address.stud_tid` so your joins are all equal. Drop a record from one of those two tables and rerun and you will see different results.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your data are complete. Every student has an address.
If you remove one or more addresses, results will be different.